# Why is [UIImage imageNamed] displaying a blue rectangle instead of my image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm trying to use an image for a button in the Nav Bar.  It appears to be finding the image, because when I run the app, there is blue rectangle roughly the size of my image centered on where the nav bar button is supposed to be.  And when I click it, the action specified for the button happens. But why is the image not displayed?  Here's my code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newTweetSmall"];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newTweet)];
```

I've also tried

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"newTweetSmall"];
```

But that appears to not be finding the image at all, because there is no big blue rectangle, no button in the Nav Bar at all.

Here's the structure of my project, in case that matters. I've also tried using 'Resources/newTweetSmall' for the path of the image, but that results in no image or button either.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the Images.xcassets way instead of the resources folder directly?

Comment: No. I'm doing this to learn Xcode/iOS Programming, so I have no idea what you're talking about ;-)

Comment: Ha okay, I just meant, that in your screenshoot you have the Images.xcassets. You can add image into that thing and use [UIImage imageNamed:@"newTweetSmall"].

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Try use a png image with alpha channel.

It certainly solve your problem.

If you want to be convinced that your file was loaded to memory check the value in the image variable. If image is loaded this variable cannot be nil.

Comment: I already did that. No change. I also edited the question to try to bring it up to this latest version of using .png instead of .jpg.

Comment: give me the link to this file

Comment: blue rectangle appear when image has no alpha channel

Comment: I don't think that's the case; I loaded the image into GIMP, and the option to Add Alpha Channel was disabled, leading me to believe it does have an alpha channel

Comment: this file has no alpha channel.

Comment: take a look at this link (sample file with alpha channel) http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/settings-gear-ios-7-interface-symbol_17214

Comment: Sorry, your file has alpha channel. This does not change the fact that there is something wrong with the file. Your code is correct.

Comment: In your first comment you said that you passed from jpg to png: how did you create that file? From GIMP or simply changing the file extension?